# as/400 RPG pointers & addresses

Tags: pointers, ibm-midrange, rpgle

On the AS/400, in RPG is there any way to set a pointer address to the value of the variable instead of the address of the variable itself?

example:

```
    variable = 'NewVariable'
```

where the value would be an actual variable used inside of the program

`pointer = %addr('NewVariable')`  vs   `pointer = %addr(variable)`

`address of value`                vs    `address of variable`

Comment: You asked about the "value of the variable", but then you show the example as being the value of literal constant. Can you show an actual example? There doesn't seem much point in referencing the "address" of a literal constant.

Answer (score 6):

No.

If you need two levels of indirection, use C or C++.  It's pretty easy to integrate C/C++ functions with RPG if you wrap the C++ functions inside a service program.

What are you trying to do that you need a pointer to a pointer to a variable?  Perhaps there's a different approach that will solve the actual business problem.

Comment: I applaud your attempt to interpret the question in a meaningful way, perhaps the only plausible way. The question as written doesn't make sense (as a commenter and another answerer have expressed).

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't make much sense.  Since RPG is a compiled language, variables only exist  in source code.  Addresses only exist during the execution of a program.

A variable is just the name given (in the source code) to (what will be) a certain number of bytes at a given address during runtime.

```
 d var1                          10a
 d var2                          10a   based(myPtr)
 d myPtr                           *  

    myPtr = %addr(var1);
    var1 = 'Hi';
    dsply var1;
    var2 = 'Bye';
    dsply var1;
```

displays

Hi

Bye

Answer (score 1):

When you say `variable = 'NewVariable'`, that raises the question whether you may be thinking along the lines of JVM or .NET languages, or dynamic interpretive languages.  You cannot create new variables at run-time.*

When you say want to be able to say `%addr('some value')` as opposed to `%addr( someVariable )`, I am not sure what it is you are trying to accomplish.  An unnamed literal constant is not directly addressable in any language I can think of.

But suppose there were a label on the location of that literal value.  You could effectively accomplish this with

```
     d someVal         s             10a   inz( 'some value' )

       myPtr = %addr(someVal);
```

You can treat `someVal` as a mnemonic constant.